# What is the --> operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

I was reading some JavaScript code and I came across an operator which I had never seen before: `-->`. I can't find it documented anywhere. Is this new? Or is it some kind of pointer syntax like C? Example:

```
while (x-->min) { }
```